# Carrier wave multiple file upload using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

i am using [Carrierwave file upload](http://richonrails.com/articles/allowing-file-uploads-with-carrierwave). It is working fine with single file upload. 
Is there any way for multiple uploads using the same code?

my model:

```
class EmpDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AttachmentUploader
  validates :emp_name, :avatar, presence: true
end
```

avatar/uploader.rb:

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end

def filename
  "#{model.emp_name}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
end
```

emp_detail/_form.html.erb:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :emp_name, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :emp_name, :class => 'text_field' %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :avatar , :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.file_field :avatar, :class => 'file_field' %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.submit "Create Emp Details", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <%= f.submit "cancel", method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to cancel' } %>
</div>
```

Comment: [Multiple file uploads](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads) section in Carrierwave README.

Comment: Read the documentation. There is a paragraph for multiple file uploads. https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads